# How does $scope.apply() work exactly in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I often updated model variables corresponding to DOM expression ({{}}) within the controllers. e.g.

```
$scope.myVar = new_value;
```

Some times the corresponding DOM expression **{{myVar}}** is updated automtically, others it's not.

I understand that sometimes we need to call **$scope.$apply** but...

- I don't understand **when** I should call it
- Some times I call it (let's say, just to be "sure") but I get this error (I guess since it's already being executed):

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.6/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply essentially "refreshes" your front end with the changes that had occurred to your scope.

Most of the time you dont need to do apply as it already is done for you.

Lets say that you do an ng-click(); Apply is done for you.

However, there are cases where apply is not triggered, and you must do it yourself.

Example with a directive:

```
 .directive('someCheckbox', function(){
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
     link: function($scope, $el, $attrs) {
       $el.on('keypress', function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         if(event.keyCode === 32 || event.keyCode === 13){
           $scope.toggleCheckbox();
           $scope.$apply();
         }
       });
     }
   }
 })
```

I have made changes to my scope but no apply was done for me thus i need to do it myself.

Another example with a timeout:

```
$scope.getMessage = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.message = 'Fetched after two seconds';
    console.log('message:' + $scope.message);
    $scope.$apply(); //this triggers a $digest
  }, 2000);
};
```

[Understanding apply and digest](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)

Comment: that was clear. However I don't understand what these "cases" are

Comment: One example is if you use javascript setTimeout(), there is no way of angular knowing that your scope has changed unless you call an apply. Let me update my answer with an example.

Comment: And don't forget to include your code inside $apply method (rather than calling it alone at the very end) as it provides better error handling

Answer (score 2):

A good way to understand the purpose of `$scope.apply()` is to understand that basically it does an internal `.digest()` within angular to make sure the scope is in sync (double check if anything has changed, etc).

**Most** of the time, you never need it! Most typical angular things you'll do, `ng-click` for example, will automatically trigger it for you when you make any changes to the `scope`.

But take as an example a jQuery UI dialogBox.

---

Let's say you prompt the user something, and you need to update your `scope` when they push the **OK** button.

Angular isn't aware of that button, nor does it know when any event is fired on it.

Hence, this is a very common use-case for `$scope.apply()`

Inside of that **OK** buttons event, you'd simply do:

```
$scope.apply(function () {

    // Angular is now aware that something might of changed

    $scope.changeThisForMe = true;

});
```

> In a nutshell `$scope.$apply` tells Angular and **any watchers that values have been changed and to go back and check if there are any new values**. This keeps things within the Angular context regardless of how you made a change, like in a DOM event, jQuery method, etc.